# How to Mock render prop for Controller method from React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

When running tests with the react testing library, the render prop is not covering, how do I mock that prop or how can I test it?

Code component:

```
<div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <Controller
            control={control}
            name={name}
            rules={validate}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value, name: iName } }) => (
                <select
                    name={iName}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        onChange(e.target.value);
                        action.handleInputValidation(e);
                    }}
                    onFocus={(e) => action.handleOnfocus(e)}
                    value={value}
                >
                    <option value="">{placeholder}</option>
                    {data.map((option) => (
                        <option
                            key={`option-${option.value}`}
                            value={option.value}
                        >
                            {option.label}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            )}
        />
    </div>
```

component test file:

```
describe('Component', () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = render(
            <InputComponent
                name={name}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                label={label}
                data={dataSchema}
                controller={Controller}
                register={jest.fn()}
            />
        );
    });

    test('InputComponent should be rendered', () => {
       // run expects
    });
});
```

Cover render prop for Controller method

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to say here but I assume that you want to test components that rendered by `Controller`.

What I suggest here is that in order to see rendered components by `Controller`, you have to assign `defaultValues` to your initial `useForm`(which provide `control` variable for you to pass down to your Controller).

You could use this approach to wrap your ControllerComponent file:

```js
const Wrapper = ({ children }: WrapperProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: data.reduce((acc, config) => {
      acc[config.key] = config.value;
      return acc;
    }, {} as Record<string, any>),
  });
  return children(control);
};
```

Then render it:

```js
<Wrapper>
  {(control, watch) => (
    <YourControllerComponent
      control={control}
      watch={watch}
    />
  )}
</Wrapper>
```